# Add Webpage to ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I realize this is a very basic and probably foolish question.

I am putting together a website for the first time in asp.net, and am having trouble with RedirectToAction.

I've added a cshtml page to test redirecting to, and it is failing to locate the file.

Under ~/View/Shared

I've added Test.cshtml.

On validation of Login/Authentication, I am attempting to update the method with the following....

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("Test", "Home");
                //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I've added the following line as seen above.

```
RedirectToAction("Test", "Home");
```

However, each time I try to run the code, I get a 
    Server Error in '/' Application.

Which then says it cannot locate /Home/Test..

Realizing this is my first attempt to use asp.net and MVC with it, I am a bit confused why a simple redirect statement isn't able to find the webpage.

What am I doing stupidly?

Comment: please reframe your question & title, its hard to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning `RedirectToAction("Test", "Home")`, you are essentially redirecting to an action - not to a view as you setup your `Test.cshtml`. To respond to /home/test, you would need a HomeController object with a Test action to handle the request. To just return your view since it is shared, you can have your method to return `View("Test")`, which would find your test.cshtml file in your shared directory.

MVC operates heavily on conventions. If you want to have `/Home/Test` respond to a redirect request (specifically `RedirectToAction("Test", "Home"), you need a few things:

1. `HomeController` controller (and assumed default MVC routing of {ControllerName}/{ActionName}
2. `Test` action method that returns a view (even `return View()` is fine)
3. In Views\Home folder in project, a Test.cshtml file containing your view.